# Node preview in a POPUP

Tags: nodes, entities, javascript

I Want to open node preview in popup,

Is it possible to display Node Preview in a pop up like colourbox or light box?

If anyone has solution Please let me know

Thanks..!!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Colorbox node](https://www.drupal.org/project/colorbox_node) module. you could show any node or view in a colorbox.

Comment: Show, yes. But can you connect it with preview button? If so, please share a way to do it. If no, then you aren't answering the question asked here.